# Order Precedence || Order of Operations

Tags: java

I was working through some code in the classroom and came across the following:

```
int x 14; 
int y 3; 

x = x-- % y--'
```

The result after compiling is 
'x = 2 '
'y = 2'

I am having a very difficult time understanding the order or operations for this particular scenario.
My logic based off of Oracles Operators Precedence
(Here)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Would conclude:
x = (x = x -1 ) % ( y = y - 1)  (because of order precedence)

Therefore: x = 13 % 2

x = 1

y = 2

I am wrong please tell me why.  I have horse blinders on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value of the expression `x--` is the value *before* the decrement - not the value *after* it.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you convert your comment to an answer, I shall upvote it.  No other comment or answer is necessary for this question.

Comment: The x-- is a post modification, so it would be applied after the rest of the calculation. Your assumption would be correct if it was --x

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Not "after the rest of the calculation" - it occurs before any of the rest of the statement, it's just that the value of the expression is the value *before* the decrement.

Comment: I hope your class isn't teaching you to write code like that!  It's confusing to assign a variable to an expression, and decrement or increment the same variable inside the same expression; in some languages other than Java, where the order of operations isn't clearly defined, this could have different results on different compiler implementations.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for the clarification...I just knew it wasn't part of the calculation and was the best way I could wrap my head around it and describe it...

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
int x = 2;
println(x--);
```

prints 2 but leaves `x` at 1. Suffix increment and decrement give you the value *before* the variable is altered.

This:

```
int x = 2;
println(--x);
```

prints 1 and leaves `x` at 1. Prefix increment and decrement give you the value *after* the variable is altered.

EDIT:

If you assign to `x` in the same expression, the assignment happens last.

```
int x = 3;
x = 2*(x--);
```

The value of `x--` is 3 (the value before `x` is decremented). So after the assignment, `x` ends up with the value 6 in this case.

So for your example:

```
int x = 14;
int y = 3;

x = x-- % y--;
```

The value of `x--` is 14 (the value before `x` is decremented). The value of `y--` is 3 (the value before `y` is decremented). So `x` gets assigned to `14%3==2`. `y` is left at its decremented value, 2.

Comment: That's only part of the answer.  The example in the question uses `x--` in the RHS of an assignment statement that assigns the variable x.  What does `x = x--;` do?

Comment: @jameslarge ok, added more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`x--` return `x` and decrease after.

```
x = 14, y = 3
x = 14 % 3 → 2,  (x = x - 1 → 13 is done before the x receive  14 % 3 → 2)
y = y - 1 → 2
```

`--x` decrease and return `x`

Comment: You right, I changed. I have a doubt the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens:

```
int temp = (x % y);
x--;
y--;
x = temp;
```